# Importing tensorflow into an Android project

Tags: android, gradle

I am building an android project which has a dependency on the android Tensorflow library. [This tutorial](https://omid.al/posts/2017-02-20-Tutorial-Build-Your-First-Tensorflow-Android-App.html) suggests downloading nightly build artefacts and manually placing them into your project.

Is there a more programmatic way of adding this dependency to my system? In python one would use `pip` for instance. I am new to android development and am surprised that this isn't trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:1.2.0'
}
```

to my `build.gradle` file and this seems to be working. Finding documentation on this wasn't as simple as I expected.